# Riak-JS doesn't respond to 'keys' function

Tags: node.js, riak

I reinstalled riak, node.js and riak-js on a new sever (Ubuntu 13.04) and suddenly when I use Riak-JS's db.keys() to get a list of keys in a bucket, it simply never returns.

Here's a test snippet that shows how it fails:

```
var db = require('riak-js').getClient();

console.log('1');
db.save('bkt','x','1', function(err, data) {
    console.log('2');
    db.get('bkt','x', function(err, data) {
            console.log('3:'+data);
            db.keys('bkt', function(err, list) {
                    console.log('4');
                    for (key in list) { console.log('5:'+list[key]); }
            });
    });
});
```

Here's the output:

```
1

2

3:1
```

It doesn't output anything else.  I installed the latest Riak (1.4.2), Node.js and Riak-JS (@latest).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://riakjs.com/#keys) `db.keys()` returns event emitter instead of passing the result to the callback. It's because the key list may be very long.

In that case the callback serves only to handle errors.

So instead of passing the callback, you have to use the returned even emitter:

```
db.keys('bkt', function(err) {                                            
        if (err) {                                                              
            //handle error                                                      
        }                                                                       
})                                                                              
    .on('keys', function(list) {                                                
        //handle the keys list                                                  
        //remember, keys may be delivered in batches                            
    })                                                                          
    .on('end', function() {                                                     
       //handle the end of keys stream                                          
    })                                                                          
    .start();
```

Comment: Thanks -- It makes much more sense that way but I had working code under an older version that worked the way described above.  I didn't realize it had changed.  Thanks again.

Comment: Anything special that must be done in on('end')? 
I seem to get the string 'null' logged to the console when riak.keys terminates, not sure how to avoid it..

Comment: @matt we need you to show us some code, preferably in it's own question